# Wordpress loop filtering by posts which have Buddypress author avatars?

Tags: wordpress, loops, filter, buddypress, avatar

I have a basic wordpress loop displaying 5 random posts from a custom post type -

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'home',
    'showposts' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
            );
```

Inside the loop I'm displaying the authors profile image as set in Buddypress as follows -

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $post->post_author, 330 ); ?>
```

How could I alter my loop to only display posts if the author has set a Buddypress avatar, and ignore it if not?

Answer (score 0):

This is a WP function:   `get_avatar`
This is the BP function: `bp_core_fetch_avatar`

You can check if a user has a non-gravatar avatar like so:

```
if ( bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $post->post_author, 'no_grav' => true, 'html' => false ) ) != bp_core_avatar_default( 'local' ) ) {
            // show the post
}
```

Re your comment - That's a problem. There is no meta data to be check in the post query. You could:

- create that meta for each person - a rather involved process
- get all the ids of members with avatars and use the `author__in`
  parameter in `WP_Query` - not very efficient if you have a lot of
  members
- Call more posts so that you get at least 5 with author avatars

Comment: Thanks for this, how would I incorporate it into the loop though so I get 5 posts that do have avatars?